# ¿Cómo ir distribuyendo una cantidad total entre pequeños grupos?

Tags: python, funciones, bucles

Os cuento la situación, que es un poco liosa.

Parto de un input introducido por el usuario: 4, por ejemplo:

```
botellas=4
```

Luego establezco 3 categorías, cada una con una cifra (son porcentajes). Por ejemplo:

A=30
B=65
C=5

Luego creo una tupla y la ordeno de mayor a menor.

```
tupla=[("A",A),("B",B),("C",C)]

tupla_ordenada=sorted(tupla,key=lambda categoria:categoria[1], reverse=True)
```

Hemos partido de 4 botellas (por poner un nombre de ejemplo). Ahora necesito crear tantos bloques como "botellas" tenga, partiendo de un total de 100 para tener %. Así, con 4 botellas, tendría 4 bloques de 25%.

Vale.

Genial. Ahora viene la duda.

Lo que tengo que hacer es distribuir, para las categorías A,B y C las botellas que les correspondan en función de las cantidades que tenga cada una empezando por la categoría más grande.

En este caso, categoría B=65.

Tengo que asignar las 4 botellas, cada una de las cuales tiene un valor de 25. Entonces, a la Categoría B le corresponde una botella. Lo que sucede ahora es que del total de B (65) le resto el valor de la botella que ha conseguido. Es decir, 65-25=40.

Ahora B=40, y tiene 1 botella.

Ahora, pasamos a la siguiente categoría: A=30 y hacemos lo mismo: 30-25=5 -> A=5, y tiene una botella.

Lo que sucede ahora cambia las cosas. La siguiente categoría (C=10) no tiene suficiente valor como para recibir una botella (10<25), por tanto vamos a la siguiente categoría que sí es igual o superior a 25: B (que ahora tenía un valor de 40).

Le asignamos una botella más. Ahora B=15.

Repasemos:

B=15 (tiene 2 botellas)
A=5 (tiene 1 botella)
C=10 (tiene 0 botellas)

Y queda 1 botella por asignar, con un "valor" de 25.
Ninguna de las categorías alcanza el valor de 25, por tanto, se elige ahora la que tenga el valor más elevado. De nuevo, es B (15). Por tanto, le asignamos una botella más.

Así,
B=3 botellas
A=1 botella
C=0 botellas

Esto, de forma automática...

Ni idea de como afrontarlo. He pensado en un bucle, pero no lo sé.

¿Alguna ayuda, por favor?

Muchísimas gracias!

Un saludo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta describe perfectamente cuál es el problema e incluso cómo debe solucionarse paso a paso. Tu pregunta por tanto está dando el *algoritmo* para resolverlo.

Sólo te queda dar tres pasos:

1. Pensar qué estructuras de datos serían las más adecuadas de las que te ofrece el lenguaje (python en este caso). Ya que en cada categoría A, B o C debes guardar un par de números, uno con la capacidad libre de esa categoría y otro con el número de botellas que ya has guardado en ellas, y ya que esas cantidades van variando durante la ejecución del algoritmo, no parece que una lista de tuplas sea la mejor idea (pues las tuplas son inmutables, no se puede cambiar su valor). Yo usaría mejor una lista de listas. Otra opción podría ser un diccionario, pero los diccionarios intrínsecamente no están ordenados y tú necesitas que tus categorías lo estén. Así que una lista cuyos elementos sean a su vez listas sería una buena idea.
2. Escribir el algoritmo que describiste con palabras, usando pseudocódigo. Esto es, de nuevo con palabras, pero ya palabras más cercanas al mundo de la programación en las que aparezcan ideas de "bucles" y "condiciones".
3. Traducir el pseudocódigo al lenguaje de programación final. Siendo python este último paso no debería ser muy difícil.

Te ayudaré un poco con los pasos 1 y 2 y dejaré el 3 para tí.

Como dije más arriba yo usaría una lista para las categorías, pero los elementos de esa lista no serían tuplas, sino otras listas que incluyan el nombre de la categoría, su capacidad libre, y el número de botellas que lleven asignadas.

```
A=30
B=65 
C=5
categorias = [["A",A, 0],["B",B, 0],["C",C, 0]]
categorias = sorted(categorias, key=lambda categoria:categoria[1], reverse=True)
```

El pseudocódigo sale de leer con cuidado tu descripción del problema y expresarlo de una forma más "computable":

```
Inicializar categorías con las capacidades iniciales y cero botellas en cada una
Inicializar numero de botellas
Inicializar peso de botella (100/numero botellas)
Inicializar una variable "categoria" con el valor 0
  (esta variable dice cuál es la siguiente categoría en que debemos buscar hueco)

Hacer un bucle para cada botella en el que:
  - Se busca la primera categoría que tenga hueco
  - Si ninguna tiene hueco, se elige como categoría la que tenga máximo hueco
  - En esa categoría se reduce su capacidad en el peso de la botella
    y se incrementa en 1 el número de botellas
```

Ya estamos más cerca de la solución, pero en este pseudocódigo hay un par de frases que aún requieren algo de aclaración: "buscar la primera botella que tenga hueco".

Esto implica otro bucle interno en el que, partiendo de la categoría que tocaría mirar:

- Se mira si `categoria` tiene hueco (es decir si su capacidad es >= que el peso) y en ese caso se sale del bucle interno
- Si no, se incrementa categoría "circularmente" (lo que significa que si al sumarle 1 te pasas del número de categorías existente, vuelves a 0, de modo que tras la categoría "C" se miraría de nuevo la "A") y se sigue en el bucle.
- El bucle debe repetirse hasta encontrar una con capacidad >= peso, o bien hasta que el bucle haya sido iterado N veces, siendo N el número de categorías (que es la longitud de la lista `categorias`. Así que necesitas otra variable para ver cuántas veces has repetido este bucle interno.

Cuando salgas del bucle interno será, bien porque has encontrado una categoría destino, o porque has iterado ya N veces (has visitado todas las categorías sin encontrar sitio). Así que puedes mirar si al salir del bucle la `categoria` elegida tiene sitio, y la usarías, o no tiene sitio, en cuyo caso pasarías a la otra estrategia: buscar la categoría con máximo espacio y usar esa como destino.

Creo que ya tienes ingredientes para pensar en una implementación. Si lo consigues, puedes publicar tu propia respuesta. Si te atascas, puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el código que has intentado hasta ese momento y explicar dónde y por qué te has atascado.

Comment: Excelente. Me has ayudado muchísimo, y he conseguido sacarlo. Te lo agradezco muchísimo!!